# matlab interp2 function for image interpolation on Python?

Tags: python, matlab, image-processing

```
for channel = 1 : numChannels
 im_out(:, :, channel) = interp2(x_out, y_out, im_in(:, :, channel),
x_in, y_in);
end
```

I have funtion like this on matlab , I tried

> Interp2d, RectBivariateSpline

but couldnt make on python.
What is equivalent on python ?

Answer (score 0):

The [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/) package provide the [cv.resize](https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga47a974309e9102f5f08231edc7e7529d) funcion for 2D image interpolation. OpenCV can be installed via pip:

`pip install opencv`

Example for resizing an image (with cubic interpolation):

```
import cv2
img_out= cv2.resize(src=img_in, dsize=(320,200),interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
```

Hereby img_in can be gray-valued as well as rgb or rgb-alpha image.